# Scientist gets stuck in a two dimensional plane

Tags: story-identification, novel

I can't seem to recall the title of a specific story.

The story was about a scientist, who, while testing out a machine that a former scientist was injured by, gets stuck in a two dimensional plane. He realizes by closing his eyes he can move about freely. The story concludes when he realizes that the plane is actually a Mobius strip and is able to turn off the machine before it exploded.

It was in an anthology with a preface by Isaac Asimov

I read it roundabout four or five years ago.

Comment: Sounds a little similar to "[The 4D Doodler](http://www.4dlab.info/Waldeyer4D.pdf)" by Graph Waldeyer, but that involves the 4th Dimension. However, there is a machine of sorts (it's a geometric construct) and people do get stuck in a different dimensional plane (the 4th dimension). Injuries do occur, in a sense - they are interpreted as injuries when its really just the ability to see "inside" parts of bodies due to their being in a different dimension. It lacks the Moebius and the exploding machine. It is from 1941. Read it for free by clicking the link above.

Answer (score 3):

Sifting through my library, I found the short story. It's "Turnabout" in a book titled *[Ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ends)*, by Gordon Dickson, also available via the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/1955-01_IF#page/n87/mode/2up).

Comment: Could you also add how you determined this was the novel you were looking for? Some plot details, maybe? This might help future visitors.

Comment: . . . or possibly link to reviews/on line sources etc

Comment: And which short story is it?

Comment: Glad you found your story. Just out of curiosity, why did you use the "novel" tag?